Windows 10, Python 3, PyCharm не находит init.tcl из-за чего не работает tkinter
Столкнулся с проблемой, при попытке запустить программу написанную с помощью tkinter:
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Окошко')
root.geometry('300x200')

label = Label(text='ПРОСТО ТЕКСТОВЫЙ ВИДЖЕТ')
label.pack()

root.mainloop()


Выдаёт ошибку:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\skorp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\PycharmProjects\TEST\Collections\GUI_COLLECTION.py", line 24, in <module>
    root = Tk()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2459, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    {C:/Users/skorp/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/PycharmProjects/TEST/.venv/lib/tcl8.6} C:/Users/skorp/PycharmProjects/TEST/.venv/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/skorp/PycharmProjects/TEST/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/skorp/PycharmProjects/TEST/.venv/library C:/Users/skorp/PycharmProjects/TEST/library C:/Users/skorp/PycharmProjects/TEST/tcl8.6.14/library C:/Users/skorp/PycharmProjects/tcl8.6.14/library


Вне Pycharm всё нормально работает. Папки tcl8.6 в директории PyCharm нет.
Не нашёл чёткого ответа, хотя проблема вроде в PyCharm распространённая.

Если Python 3.13 - проверьте, что у вас 3.13.1, а не 3.13.0. У 3.13.0 проблемы с работой tkinter, когда используется виртуальное окружение.

У меня стоит Python 3.13.0

Вот и ответ. Обновитесь до 3.13.1 или откатитесь до более старой версии.

Проблему решил просто скопировав нужные папки tcl8.6 из папки интерпретатора в папку Lib, как указано в ошибке. Теперь всё работает)

Это костыль. Не нужно вручную редактировать виртуальное окружение. Виртуальное окружение должно создаваться парой команд (создание + установка зависимостей), без ручного добавления каких-то файлов.

Вернул всё как было, обновил Python, другая ошибка
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:      {C:\Python\tcl\tcl8.6} C:/Python/tcl/tcl8.6/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.14, need exactly 8.6.15 version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.14, need exactly 8.6.15     while executing "package require -exact Tcl 8.6.15"     (file "C:/Python/tcl/tcl8.6/init.tcl" line 21)     invoked from within "source C:/Python/tcl/tcl8.6/init.tcl"     ("uplevel" body line 1)     invoked from within "uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]" 

Тут какой-то конфликт версий tcl. Я бы попробовал для начала виртуальное окружение полностью удалить и создать новое, если не поможет - Python полностью удалить вместе с его папкой, потом установить заново.

Установить Питон 3.13.1, включив все компоненты КРОМЕ "Download free-threaded binaries (experimental)". Обновить установку ВСЕХ используемых модулей. Предыдущие установку лучше удалить. К сожалению, удаление не производится полностью. Надо дочищать вручную, но это нужно уметь.

@insolor
Создание нового виртуального окружения не помогает, потому что в таковом попросту не создаётся так необходимой папочки tcl8.6

Ни полная переустановка Python, ни создание других виртуальных сред не решает проблемы. Остаётся только хромать, используя с костыли(

В общем, tkinter заработал с python 3.13.1, проблема второй ошибки была в том, что pycharm начинал поиск в старом виртуальном окружении, в котором был по-прежнему установлен python 3.13.0, отсюда и сообщении о конфликте версий init.tcl. Решилось маркировкой Sources root папки Scripts нового виртуального окружения, в котором уже был python 3.13.1/ не уверен, что здесь стоит писать ответ.

@AsLimbo а, ну это бывает. PyCharm не дает нормально удалить используемое виртуальное окружение, нужно PyCharm закрыть перед удалением.
